# How to receive params in intent for broadcast

Tags: java, android, broadcast, android-broadcast

```
Integer id_user = 1;
Intent registration= new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
                                registration.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),0,new Intent(),0));
                                registration.putExtra("sender",project_number);
                                startService(registration);
```

i need put extra similar

registration.putExtra("id_user",id_user);

and recieved in broadclass

```
public class resquest extends BroadcastReceiver {

NEED CATCH HERE..... a USER_ID

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      .....Code here 
    }
}
```

Regards!

Comment: What type is id_user? Are you asking just how to fetch id_user, or how to fetch the other two params you post in your example?

Comment: Hello, i need fetch id_user in class resquest

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to send in the user id to be able to fetch it:

```
Integer id_user = 1;
Intent registration= new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
                            registration.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),0,new Intent(),0));
                            registration.putExtra("sender",project_number);
                            registration.putExtra("id_user", id_user.intValue());
                            startService(registration);
```

Then you can fetch it like this

```
public class resquest extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int id_user = i.getExtras().getInt("id_user");
    }
}
```